# Is DTO and Adapter patterns compatible?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I have an architectural question. Can I use `Adapter Pattern` with `DTO Pattern` from the OOP design's point of view?

Comment: Can you point to real examples without trolling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why shouldn't you? The adapter pattern even offers itself to be used with DTOs. You can use it to "translate" your DTOs into whatever is suitable for your application and back.

Lets say you have an API that is using DTOs. Now you want to use that API. There could be a lot of reasons why you don't want to use the DTOs in your client code as they are. Maybe your client already exists and you don't wan't to change it. Or the data structure of the DTOs is just not suitable to be shown in a GUI. In this case you can introduce an adapter. It's API would use the classes used in your client and it would call your existing API with the DTOs.

Comment: Every time when I use Adapter I change an interface of adaptee. But DTO has only setters and gettters so what behavior I can change in this case? I mean I can't change getters and settres.

Comment: By Adapter I mean Java class.

Comment: Okay. Now I see a reasonable grain in your answer :) Thanks.